# iphone - UIAnimation Fade Between two colors like "Touch to return to call" box

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, fade, uianimation

I have a UIView with a label inside that appears at the bottom of my app. I'm trying to create an animation like the one that appears when you are in a call and touch the home button.

It seems like a fade transition that loops between two colors (light green and strong green in the call box).

I also have a NStimer that I think I could use for looping this.

Any ideas in how to accomplish?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background color is supposed to be animatable (however, as others have found UILabel doesn't seem to support that, but other views do). Try that and see where it takes you. I think you could dig down to CA layer keyframes to control the color stepping.

You might also try having one layer with one color and another colored layer on top of that and animating the alpha of the top layer.

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
[window addSubview:v];
[v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 
delay:0 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse                
animations:^
{
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
completion:nil 
];
```

Comment: But I have an UIVIew with a UILabel inside. What I want to animate is the UIView and th text to remain visible. Try to make a phone call nd hit the home button and look at the top bar to see what I want to accomplish.

Comment: UILabel is subview of your view, so its rendered on top of your UIView, so background color can be animated and text color will not be effected. Alternately, if you copy and paste the UIView/UILayer in IB and put the second one on top of the first, the upper UIView's background color could be changed but because the text on that label is again on top of that level, it will appear that the text color isn't changed.

Comment: Do you have a code example of something like this? I mean, for the fade in, fade out betweem two colors loop animation

Comment: Added code to answer that just animates the color of the uiview. (pasting code into these comment boxes doesn't format well).

Comment: So the UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse will go back to the previous color? I'll try this at home

Comment: Yup, it might revert back to red at the end. Add a completion and set color to blue in above example to get it to end on blue. Play around with it and you will see . An upvote would be appreciated :)